# How to stop Button ActionListener midway and wait for the user to click it again?

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I'm really in need for a solution to this problem and haven't yet found a solution even after 2 hours of searching. I am learning Java AWT by developing simple apps.

I have created a Sign Up page/window/frame which takes a username, a password and a confirmation password through their respective TextFields and adds them to the database, when the "Sign Up" button is clicked, if and only if the two passwords match. If they don't match, the password text fields are cleared and the user needs to re-enter the values and click on the "sign Up" button again. This needs to go on in a loop. I have put all the lines of required code, including the passwords-not-equal logic, in the ActionListener of the "Sign Up" button.

I am posting the button's ActionListener part of my code. You'll notice obvious logical errors such as, after clearing the passwords' TextFields using `setText("")`, the passwords actually match since both are empty strings. But still, even if I clear only one of the two TextFields, once the ActionListener is executed, I am not able to re-enter the new values in the TextFields and the app hangs forever, until force closed.

```
signupButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {               
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String confirmPass = "";

        do
        {
            username = usernameTF.getText();
            password = passwordTF.getText();
            confirmPass = confirmPassTF.getText();

            Label passErrorMsg = new Label("Passwords do not match. Enter again.");

            if(password.equals(confirmPass))
            {
                passErrorMsg.setVisible(false);
                break;
            }

            passErrorMsg.setBounds(70, 320, 205, 20);
            signupWindow.add(passErrorMsg);
            passErrorMsg.setVisible(true);

            passwordTF.setText(""); //If I comment this statement, the app hangs.
            //Else in the next iteration, the loop breaks since both the strings become empty

            confirmPassTF.setText("");

        }while(true);

       //Some more lines of code to work with the database
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions so we can read your code. There is no need for a loop. When then use clicks the button you validate the data. If valid you continue. If not you clear the data and wait for them to re-enter the data and click on the button again

Comment: . `I am learning Java AWT by developing simple apps.` not sure why you would start with AWT. You should at least use Swing (even it is getting old). It is basically the same except you use "JLabel" and "JTextField" etc. Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics.

Comment: @camickr I think I've understood it. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @camickr I am learning both AWT and Swing. I'm required to.

Comment: I think you miss the point. Swing is build on top of AWT so there are lots of AWT classes used by Swing. But you should be using Swing components when you build your GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop does not belong, as while it is fine for a linear console program, will block the Swing event thread or any other event thread in an event-driven program, rendering the program frozen and useless. Instead you will probably want to simply clear the dialog's text fields if the input is wrong and display an error message in a JOptionPane. In fact, likely all you need is the if / else block and no while loop:

```
SignupButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {               
        String Username = "";
        String Password = "";
        String ConfirmPass = "";

        Username = UsernameTF.getText();
        Password = PasswordTF.getText();
        ConfirmPass = ConfirmPassTF.getText();

        if(Password.equals(ConfirmPass)) {
            PassErrorMsg.setVisible(false);

            // do database stuff here

        } else {
            // here clear fields and show an error message
            // consider incrementing an error count as well
        }
    }
});
```

Again the key issue is that when creating an event-driven program, you must think in a *non-linear* event-driven way. Linear console code logic will not work (in these situations).

Other issues: You shouldn't use Strings to hold passwords since these will be interned into the String pool can be hacked pretty easily. Also, yes as Camickr states, learn and follow Java naming conventions, including starting variable and method names with lower case letters and class names with upper case letters. Avoid using `setBounds(...)` and `null` layouts as these lead to GUI's that don't work well on all platforms. Instead learn and use the layout managers.

Comment: I realized how easy the solution was. Maybe I need some rest. I have changed the variable names in the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do-while iterations if the functions/methods should be triggered only once on button-click, your code above probably ends up in infinite loop.